# Opening zip files within a zip file

Tags: javascript, zip, jszip

I have a zip file (call it a.zip) where a.zip contains a series of zip files (0.zip, 1.zip...n.zip). The value of 'n' depends on how big the original file that we were processing is. Each of the 0-n.zip files are limited in size so we can (in theory) process large files by breaking them into smaller chunks and then processing the smaller chunks.

Using javascript, I need to open a.zip and send each of the 0-n.zip files to our server for processing.

I have been able to successfully do this using:

```
   function processZipFile(input) {
        JSZip.loadAsync(input.files[0]).then(function (zip) {
             zipFiles = zip;
             numberOfFiles = 0;
             zip.forEach(function () {
                  numberOfFiles = numberOfFiles + 1;
             }
         });
         uploadZipFile(0);
   } 

function uploadZipFile(fileCount) {
    zipFiles.file(fileCount).async("blob").then(function (blob) {
        'post file to server'
        'on success increment file count and, if less than number of files, upload next file'
        'on failure retry upload up to three times'
    }
}
```

Using this, I was able to upload a 250MB file without issue. Our customer now has a 1GB file which hangs the loadAsync call.

Is there a way that I can access each of the 0-n.zip files and process them without having to load the entire zip file, since I know each of these files are limited in size and can be loaded and sent to the server?

Comment: The reason of this is to give a feedback to user of how many files or size is left? I ask that because there are others ways to show progress based on events: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/progress_event

Comment: The showing of progress is a 'nice to have'. The problem is getting back to the original file when I have a large original file. What happens is we have a user create the a.zip file on any computer, then they have to upload it on a private network. Each 0-n.zip file includes data from the original file, a key to decrypt the data and several files. Each of the 0-n files needs to be uploaded, decrypted and the data re-assembled to get back to the original file. The process is working for an almost 250MB file, but at some point the file size is too large and hangs the asyncload.